# Exporting R lm model with multiple dependent variables to csv

Tags: r, interpretation, lm

I have the following lm with a vector of dependent variables:

```
fit<-lm(cbind(X1m, X3m, X6m, X1y, X2y, X3y, X5y, X6y, X10y, 
                 X20y, X30y) ~ (ff + dc), data = yields)
```

When attempting to export the entire output to a csv file, I get this error:

```
write.csv(summary(fit),"fit.csv")
Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = stringsAsFactors) :     
cannot coerce class ""listof"" to a data.frame
```

Exporting the coefficients only yields no error:

```
write.csv(coef(fit), "fit.csv")
```

I would like, however, to have t-statistics and standard errors along with my coefficients in a neatly formatted csv, so as to copy into word documents, presentations, etc.

I know this problem has to do with the fact that the dependent variables are a list (vector). Any thoughts or suggestions would be appreciated. The sample data can be found [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qgge4y519719q9s/yields.csv?dl=0).

Comment: So what exactly would the desired output look like? Can you give an example using this test data?

Comment: the `broom` package might help you to convert `lm` output to `data.frame` that can be exported as csv files http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/broom `library(broom); tidy(fit); augment(fit); glance(fit)`

Comment: Please don't cross-post the same question on multiple sites

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap a `capture.output()` around it

```
write(capture.output(summary(fit)), "fit.txt")
```

You'll get a nice clean .txt file with everything shown in R console when you evaluate `summary(fit)`. I do not recommend writing to .csv, but you if you insist, just use `write.csv.`

And for your/future reader's reference, if you do decide to automate this process within a function, then you need to wrap a `eval(..., envir = .GlobalEnv)` to get rid of those annoying environment tags from being printed/written.